# How does github raw code work? It can display text like code without <pre> tag

Tags: html, github

I want to know why does github's raw code(like [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torvalds/linux/master/README)) appear to be formatted how it is without using `<pre>` tags.

I've tried to copy the code to a file and use browser to open it, but if I don't add a `<pre>...</pre>`, it won't display in the correct format and use  the Monospace font.

Comment: I'm sorry if this question is very simple, I'm really new to html.

Comment: In dev console you can see that it _does_ have <pre> tags.

Comment: [Screenshot Attached](http://imgur.com/dUQOFd0)

Comment: Yes it is. Why it doesn't display in page source?

Comment: You can see `<pre>` tags in the dev console, but in view-source, you'll see they weren't served by github.  The question is where did they come from?

Comment: @recursive Yes, that is my question :)

Comment: And if I had an answer I wouldn't be writing so many comments related to that question.

Comment: Nope no `<pre>` tags. View the source, that is what is rendered sent to the browser, the dev console shows how the browser interprets what is sent to the browser. Use the network tab of your dev console, and show headers to see what @recursive is talking about in his answer.

Comment: @JonP Thanks, Let me see that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then answer is in the http header.  Web pages are served with a `Content-type` header set to `text/html`.  If you use `text/plain` instead, browsers will show it as pre-formatted.

Comment: Understand now, so I should change the `Content-type` from `text/html` to `text/plain` right? :)

Comment: If you want to serve a page as plain text, yes.

Answer (score 4):

I believe what you're referring to is the browsers treatment of pages with a "Content-Type" header of "text/plain" rather than "text/html".

Since the response header for content at "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/..." is "text/plain" no browser rendering occurs.

**Example**

Even though "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mattrohland/vEwe/master/index.html" is HTML, browsers will respect the fact that it has a "Content-Type" of "text/plain" and not render it as HTML; Instead it will be presented as plain-text.

---

You can run the following command to quickly check a URL's response content type.

**Command**

`curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mattrohland/vEwe/master/index.html -I | grep Content-Type:`

**Result**

`Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`

Comment: Yes, just like @recursive said. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

README files on Github use [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) text-to-html conversion tool. You can learn more [here](https://help.github.com/articles/markdown-basics/). You can check one of those WYSIWYG markdown online tools to try writing some markdown based text.

Comment: It's just a example, this question is about `<pre>` tag. I'm **not** asking about **Markdown**.

Comment: understand. I was looking at the Readme and was misled. i believe the answer was explained well above. thanks for the correction.